# Binding Click function to class is not working

Tags: jquery, css, click

I am quite new to JQuery and having following problem with my code.
I have a HTML code as below:

```
<div id="productsBox">
    <span class="productItem">
        <img class="ProductImage" src="/media/1656/FootballShirts.png "></img>
        <span class="productName">Football Shirts</span>
        <span class="relavantSizeAdvice">2189</span>
     </span>

    <span class="productItem">
        <img class="ProductImage" src="/media/1697/FootballShorts.png "></img>
        <span class="productName">Football Shorts</span>
        <span class="relavantSizeAdvice">2189</span>
    </span>

    <span class="productItem">
        <img class="ProductImage" src="/media/1702/FootballSocks.png "></img>
        <span class="productName">FootBall Socks</span>
        <span class="relavantSizeAdvice">2189</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

I want to bind a click function to all elements with class named  "productItem". My Jquery code is as below:

```
$('.productItem').bind('click', function () {
        alert("Clicked!");
    });
```

in my code the alert never invoked, What have I missed here?

Any suggestions?

Comment: read through this http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info - its more than likely missing a document.ready tag

Comment: Possible reasons: 1) jQuery hasn't been included 2) jQuery included after this code 3) not wrapped in document.ready 4) JavaScript error somewhere in the script. Are there errors in the console?

Comment: I have used Click Bind for elements with ID as follow: $('#RegisterCustomerButton').bind('click', function () {}); and they are working fine.

Comment: Side note: The `<img>` element shouldn't have an end tag. (Either `<img />` or just `<img>` but not `<img></img>`.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably are calling your jquery code before the spans are loaded. You have two options

Do it when the [DOM is ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

```
$(function(){
    $('.productItem').bind('click', function () {
        alert("Clicked!");
    });
})
```

Or use [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', '.productItem', function(){
    alert("Clicked")
})
```

[Sample of working code](http://jsfiddle.net/jJFAT/)

Comment: `.delegate()` has been deprecated for almost 1.5 years now.

Comment: I have filled the spans dynamically but all happened before triggering this function.

Comment: @amirmoradifard Your question needs to show more of what's going on. If what I suggested didn't fix the problem, you're not showing all the relevant code. I could create an example to prove it to you... but you should do that on your won, create a simple reduction of your problem, and you'll probably figure out the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/jJFAT/

Comment: @amirmoradifard Don't post code here, please just improve your question

Comment: The question is what I have said before, I have provided the HTML and JQuery. Not sure what else is required to make it more clear!

Comment: @amirmoradifard I have provided you an example http://jsfiddle.net/jJFAT/ that proves that your code as you've posted works. There is something else that you're not showing us. Instead of saying "I've already explained it", please look at the link I posted and figure out what's different from your actual code, then ask a question with a real example that doesn't work (because your example does work if you're sure you called it after the DOM element was loaded)

Comment: @JuanMendes: Adding the ON to my Html causes none of the other JS functions working!
Isn't that because of the different versions of JQuery?

I am using version 1.2.6

Comment: @amirmoradifard Yes, `on` is only supported since 1.7; therefore, you can't do event delegation as simply as I've shown you. 1.2.6 is really old, I would consider upgrading